# Gyroscope weight under presession

Tags: forces

If you have a one pound gyro presessing around why does it take less than one pound of force added to its forward presession to lift it up?is the gyro holding that one pound of weight up and your just adding that little extra force required to move it up further?

Comment: [Does this Veritasium video help?](https://youtu.be/GeyDf4ooPdo)

Answer (score 0):

So the starting state that you refer to is a state of dynamic equilibrium, where the precessing motion gives just the amount of tendency to pitch up to counteract the downpitching force from gravity.

Let me make a comparison:
Take the case of neutral buoyancy. Let's say you are in a small submarine that is trimmed to be neutrally buoyant. Imagine a diver who positions himself underneath that submarine, and he starts to push up. The amount of force he can exert will be quite small, but since the submarine is neutrally buoyant a small force is enough to make it slowly move upwards.

Neutral buoyancy is a case of static equilibrium, gyroscopic precession keeping a gyroscope wheel from falling down is a dynamic equilibrium.

In the case of that gyroscope: adding just a little bit of extra tendency to pitch up is sufficient to make the gyroscope pitch up a little. As you describe, the little bit of extra tendency to pitch up can be added by speeding up the precessing motion. You nudge it a little and the gyroscope pitches up a bit.

Comment: Thank you i can understand that.